# Display series labels at the end of each line in Highcharts Editor

Tags: highcharts

I am a beginner in Highcharts and I am trying to achieve what has been explained in the following case using the Highcharts Editor:

[Highcharts Line Chart, display series name at the end of line series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520599/highcharts-line-chart-display-series-name-at-the-end-of-line-series)

I don't know if the same can be achieved by just using the Editor's interface but if custom code needs to be used, I can do that in the Custom Code tab of the Editor.

I tried inputting in the Custom Code section of the Highcharts Editor the code written by [jlbriggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520599/highcharts-line-chart-display-series-name-at-the-end-of-line-series) but nothing happens.

Is it possible to get a basic explanation on how to achieve what I want? 
Below is the HTML code I took from the graph I created in Highcharts Editor.

```
<div id="highcharts-825789cd-edd9-4d9e-aba4-e3a80fa42369"></div> 
<script>
(function() {
  var files = ["https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"],
    loaded = 0;
  if (typeof window["HighchartsEditor"] === "undefined") {
    window.HighchartsEditor = {
      ondone: [cl],
      hasWrapped: false,
      hasLoaded: false
    };
    include(files[0]);
  } else {
    if (window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded) {
      cl();
    } else {
      window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.push(cl);
    }
  }

  function isScriptAlreadyIncluded(src) {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
      if (scripts[i].hasAttribute("src")) {
        if ((scripts[i].getAttribute("src") || "").indexOf(src) >= 0 || (scripts[i].getAttribute("src") === "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" && src === "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js")) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function check() {
    if (loaded === files.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.length; i++) {
        try {
          window.HighchartsEditor.ondone[i]();
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
      window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded = true;
    }
  }

  function include(script) {
    function next() {
      ++loaded;
      if (loaded < files.length) {
        include(files[loaded]);
      }
      check();
    }
    if (isScriptAlreadyIncluded(script)) {
      return next();
    }
    var sc = document.createElement("script");
    sc.src = script;
    sc.type = "text/javascript";
    sc.onload = function() {
      next();
    };
    document.head.appendChild(sc);
  }

  function each(a, fn) {
    if (typeof a.forEach !== "undefined") {
      a.forEach(fn);
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (fn) {
          fn(a[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var inc = {},
    incl = [];
  each(document.querySelectorAll("script"), function(t) {
    inc[t.src.substr(0, t.src.indexOf("?"))] = 1;
  });

  function cl() {
    if (typeof window["Highcharts"] !== "undefined") {
      var options = {
        "title": {
          "text": "One year, five year and 10 year survival estimates for the 21 most common cancers in England, 1971"
        },
        "subtitle": {
          "text": "Survival estimates in 1971 (%)"
        },
        "exporting": {},
        "chart": {
          "type": "line",
          "parallelAxes": {
            "labels": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "alignTicks": true,
            "endOnTick": true,
            "max": 4,
            "maxRange": 4,
            "minorGridLineWidth": 0,
            "gridLineWidth": -1
          },
          "inverted": false,
          "height": 872,
          "alignTicks": true,
          "showAxes": false,
          "ignoreHiddenSeries": true
        },
        "series": [{
          "name": "Oesophagus",
          "turboThreshold": 0,
          "marker": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "type": "line",
          "colorByPoint": false,
          "selected": true,
          "showInNavigator": true,
          "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "label": {
            "onArea": true,
            "enabled": true
          },
          "allowPointSelect": true,
          "xAxis": 0,
          "yAxis": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Stomach",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Colon",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Rectum",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Pancreas",
          "turboThreshold": 0,
          "marker": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "type": "line"
        }, {
          "name": "Larynx",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Lung",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Melanoma of skin",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Breast",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Cervix",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Uterus",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Ovary",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Prostate",
          "turboThreshold": 0,
          "marker": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "colorByPoint": false
        }, {
          "name": "Testis",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Kidney",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Bladder",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Brain",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Hodgkin's disease",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Non-Hodgkin lymphoma",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Multiple myeloma",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Leukaemia",
          "turboThreshold": 0
        }, {
          "name": "Other cancers",
          "turboThreshold": 0,
          "label": {
            "connectorAllowed": true
          }
        }],
        "plotOptions": {
          "series": {
            "dataLabels": {
              "enabled": false
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "csv": "\"Year\";\"Oesophagus\";\"Stomach\";\"Colon\";\"Rectum\";\"Pancreas\";\"Larynx\";\"Lung\";\"Melanoma of skin\";\"Breast\";\"Cervix\";\"Uterus\";\"Ovary\";\"Prostate\";\"Testis\";\"Kidney\";\"Bladder\";\"Brain\";\"Hodgkin's disease\";\"Non-Hodgkin lymphoma\";\"Multiple myeloma\";\"Leukaemia\";\"Other cancers\"\n\"1-year\";14.7;15.3;42.6;54.1;10.2;16;16.3;74.5;74;75.6;43.7;66.1;83.3;44.9;45.4;62.8;17.6;73.9;49.4;36.8;35.4;57.3\n\"5-year\";4;5.2;25.3;23.6;2.4;4.6;4.8;40.5;51.3;59;20.5;36.9;70.5;28.5;28.9;40.9;6.6;54.2;29.3;12.1;13.1;40.4\n\"10-year\";3.3;4;23;19.1;1.3;3.1;3.2;34.9;46;55.5;17.9;25.1;69.2;23;23;33.7;5;45.2;21.7;6.8;6.6;36.9",
          "googleSpreadsheetKey": false,
          "googleSpreadsheetWorksheet": false
        },
        "legend": {
          "floating": false,
          "enabled": false,
          "verticalAlign": "bottom",
          "align": "center",
          "layout": "horizontal"
        },
        "pane": {
          "background": []
        },
        "responsive": {
          "rules": []
        },
        "colorAxis": {
          "plotLines": [{
            "label": {
              "useHTML": false,
              "text": "'series'",
              "x": 5,
              "y": 5,
              "verticalAlign": "'middle'",
              "textAlign": "'left'"
            }
          }],
          "plotBands": [{}],
          "labels": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 2
          }
        },
        "tooltip": {
          "shared": true,
          "enabled": true
        },
        "rangeSelector": {
          "enabled": false,
          "floating": false
        },
        "credits": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "xAxis": [{
          "type": "category",
          "labels": {
            "x": 0,
            "zIndex": 7
          },
          "opposite": true
        }],
        "yAxis": [{
          "title": {
            "text": ""
          },
          "labels": {
            "format": "{hide}"
          },
          "type": "linear"
        }],
        "accessibility": {
          "describeSingleSeries": false,
          "enabled": true
        }
      };
      new Highcharts.Chart("highcharts-825789cd-edd9-4d9e-aba4-e3a80fa42369", options);
    }
  }
})();
</script>
```

I just need the names of each series to be displayed at the end of each line rather than in the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Custom code" section you need to merge your custom options with the options from the editor. There should be an example of how to do that. In essense:

```
Highcharts.merge(true, options, {
  // custom code
});
```

For example, you could use `Highcharts.merge` in the following way to achieve this:

```
Highcharts.merge(true, options, {
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function () {
          // if last point
          if(this.point === this.series.data[this.series.data.length-1]) {
            return this.series.name;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

See [this Highcharts Cloud example](https://cloud.highcharts.com/show/bKlcbdAHv) of it in use.

Comment: Many thanks @halvor it worked and labels are now showing. I just need to figure out how to display all of them and maybe allow a connector line to link each series with the labels since they are too close to each other and not displaying all of them because of that.