# Series name with series color at the end of line series

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want series name at the end of line series with color of series. I am looking for similar output present here - [Highcharts Line Chart, display series name at the end of line series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520599/highcharts-line-chart-display-series-name-at-the-end-of-line-series)

I am able to include series name at the end of line series but fails to show it as color of series. This is the solution I am unable to include it in highcharter in R as it has both **single and double quotes**. R is unable to recognise it.

```
 formatter: function() {
    return '<span style="color:'+this.series.color+'">'+this.series.name+'</span>';
  }
```

My Code is shown below -

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "spline") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Demo",
           align = "center",
           style = list(
             fontFamily = "Roboto",
             color = "#444",
             fontWeight = "bold"
           )) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = iris$Species) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(labels = list(format = "{value}M")) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name   = "Sepal.Length", 
                data   = iris$Sepal.Length,
                marker = list(enabled= FALSE),
                color='red',
                lineWidth=4, 
                lineColor='red') %>% 
  hc_add_series(name   = "Petal.Length", 
                data   = iris$Petal.Length,
                marker = list(enabled= FALSE),
                type = "area", 
                color='#f6f3ef',
                lineWidth=3, 
                lineColor='#e4dcd2',
                dashStyle = "ShortDot") %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      dataLabels = list(
        enabled = TRUE,
        allowOverlap = TRUE,
        align = 'center',
        verticalAlign = 'bottom',
        style = list(fontSize = '14px', color = '#666'),
        formatter = JS("
              function() {
                  if (this.point.x == this.series.data.length - 1) {
                          return this.series.name;
                    }
                          return '';
                }")))) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat="{point.series.name}:  €<b>{point.y:,.2f}M</b><br/>", shared= TRUE) %>% 
  hc_add_theme(anacap_theme(palettes = "lightbluegolden")) %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you escape the double quotes like that since you want to keep double quotes in the markup?

```r
formatter: function() {
  return '<span style=\"color:' + this.series.color + '\">' + this.series.name + '</span>';
}
```

Comment: each point rather than each series seems to have a name, so I end up with many many names

Comment: How can we enable it only for the last point in the series in `R`?